# Link textbox to combobox - not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a WPF usercontrol with a combobox & textbox. I want the textbox to hold the value of the selected item in the combobox and it works fine if I use SelectedValue in the binding path. However if I try to use the Title column of the combobox (SelectedValue.Title) the value of the textbox is overwritten but nothing is displayed. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? My code sample is below. I am a newbie at this so please be kind :)

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboProject"  Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" TabIndex="14"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Projects}, XPath=./Project}" 
           SelectedValuePath="@Item"
           Tag="Project Number" 
           TextSearch.TextPath="@Item">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text= "{Binding XPath= @Item}" Width="90"  />
                        <TextBlock Text= "{Binding XPath= @Title}" Width="220" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="loaded" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue.Title, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, ElementName=ComboProject}"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Tag="Project Title" TabIndex="15"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `SelectedValuePath="@Item"`, so that's what `SelectedValue` has right now. Try setting it to Title and binding directly to SelectedValue:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboProject"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Projects}, XPath=./Project}" 
          SelectedValuePath="@Title">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ComboProject}" />
```

I removed some other code for clarity of example.

**EDIT :**
Ok, if you want to use `SelectedValue` for other purposes we can bind `TextBox` to `SelectedItem` instead. If the `Title` is an attribute of a selected XML node, then we can access it like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Attributes[Title].Value, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=ComboProject}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need the combobox & textbox to have different values - i.e. combobox has the Item value and textbox has the Title value.  I think my approach should work, it is based on samples I found via google, but I must be missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "have different values"? Display different values? That is set by `ItemTemplate` in ComboBox, you can have anything you like there (right now I see Item and Title showing there). TextBox is set to display `SelectedValue` (right now it's Title). Did you try my code? What didn't work?

Comment: Using SelectedValue works fine but that gives me two controls with the same data, either Title or Number. The controls are linked to underlying property fields using Tags - when I click Save, the value of the combobox is saved to the Project Number property & the textbox value to the Project Title property. Therefore I need the combobox SelectedValue set to Item and Title in the textbox. I should be able to reference the Title column according to what I have found but I just can't get it to work. Any other suggestions for me?

Comment: I can't suggest anything more cause I don't understand what you are doing. Some more code in your question would surely help. And I don't understand why are you clinging to `SelectedValue` so much, you can use `SelectedItem` which will give you the whole node, you can extract any information you like from it, @Gerry.

Comment: I thought I explained it clearly, I want the combo box to hold the project number value and when selected the corresponding title is written to the text box.  I am not clinging to selectedvalue,  I just said that works and I can't figure out how to get the value of the second column of the combo box.  Can you give me an example of how to do this please?

Comment: Thanks for your help but this just would not work for me - the Tag attribute seems to be the reason. I worked around it by changing the textbox to a second combobox and binding them with the selected index. This actually helps me in another way as user can select by project number or title so all good now.